# Hide form when user click submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using PHP and I have a form that I want to disappear/hide when the user clicks submit. It shouldn't appear/show for same user again.

form.php

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['User']))
    {
        $nameuser = $_SESSION['User'];
    }
    else
    {
            header("location:signin.php");
    }


    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <!-- Form -->
<main class="cd-main-content">
<div class="container">
<form id="question_form" novalidate action="insertswat.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-25">
                        <label for="title">Swat form</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-75">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="swat" >
                        </div>
                        </div><!--End -->
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </div>
                        </div></form><!-- End form -->
    </main>
    <!-- cd-main-content -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

insertswat.php

```
<?php
 include('config.php');

$swat=$_POST['swat'];;




// Insert data into mysql
$sql = "INSERT INTO swatreport (swat)
  VALUES ('$swat')";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      header("location:swatform.php?q=success");

    } else {
      header("location:swatform.php?q=error");
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

How could I go about this?

When user fill text field and clicks Submit
He will never see that form again

Comment: Set the innerHTML =“” on submit and if user.isLoggedin ( I made up that property just add it to the session)

Comment: if you plan on not showing the item never again you need to store that into a cookie or database(if the user has an account). So I would look more into setting cookies and reading cookies based on the mentioned condition which php can handle. Keep in mind if it is a cookie and the user deletes the cookie, it will show again until the cookie is reset or expires.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

to assign id and name like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
```

Then:

```
<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(!isset($submit)){
//Do NOT put closing curly brace
?>

<form>

//Your form you want to hide on submit

</form>

<?php
} //this is the closing curly brace
?>

//Put the stuff you want to show after submit here...
```

Answer (score 0):

> in header check if userlogged in

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){

```
header('location:login.php');
exit();
}
```

Comment: OR you can use javascript onsubmit show() and hide() function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery snippet,

```
<script>
 $( "#questions_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $("#questions_form").fadeOut(500);
  event.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```